# What does '?' represent under TTY

Tags: ssh, process, tty, ps

If you run `ps` in your terminal, you may see something like the following:

[image]

What is `?`? I'm **ssh**'ing into a Linux server, so I assume that it's just the `sshd` as it says under **CMD**, but I'm curious what the `?` is considering there is `pts/1` to represent my terminal instance.

Comment: First look at what tty means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean , then if a program is running under a (pseudo) terminal, ps will show you which. Otherwise it will just show you a "?" because it has now further knowledge. Note closing a terminal closes also all programs running under it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It shows `?` since there is no TTY (terminal interface) to which this process is attached.  This is fortunate since `sshd` is a system daemon and should not be dependent on a client session.

As mentioned in the comments, closing a session will terminate all related processes for that TTY, which is not desired for system wide processes.